# Avoiding scientific notation

Tags: json, go

I am experimenting using Go to interact with a Database and am running into 
issues when dealing with Decimal fields.

In this database most fields that are basically integer fields are 
typed as decimal with 0 precision... for example:

- Date fields are stored in YYYYMMDD format as decimal(8, 0)
- Id numbers are stored as decimal(9, 0)

Basically any int is stored as a decimal with 0 precision.

What I am attempting is to fill fields in a struct....

```
type Record struct {
    ID          uint
    CHANGE_DATE uint
    ...
}
```

But when I get the fields from the database, they often come back in a
format like this but only if the number is long enough: 2.0141208e+07

I have found that I can Scan into a float and then convert the float to
an uint like this..

```
mydate := float32(0)

for rows.Next() {
    r := Record{}
    row.Scan(&.ID, &mydate)
    myrecord.Change_date = uint(mydate)
}
```

If the ID is a large enough number then ParseInt fails and I find I have to 
do the float/int conversion as shown above.

Since I have many fields (almost all numbers) that I would need to do this with, 
I am wondering if there is a better way to go about this type conversion?

It may also be worth mentioning that this is a database from a packaged ERP
system, so changing the table definitions is not an option and the reason 
I don't just make all fields float in Go is that I am trying to output json 
and I get the scientific notation in the json output.

Comment: Monkeying around with the data type is not the answer; this is a display formatting problem.

Comment: How do you know the value comes back as `2.0141208e+07` ? Perhaps it's simply a formatting issue when you print out/display the value in some way or another.

Comment: have you looked at the big number package in the standard library? I don't know it that well but perhaps it can offer a solution.

Comment: @nos - The ParseInt failing when I do the row.Scan leads me to believe it, smaller numbers in the same exact field work fine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I would like uints to be uints even though the db has decimal(8, 0) for example.  Not sure how to do that without converting types.

Comment: None of these have fractional parts (they're decimal(n, **0**)), so not sure why to scan into scan into `float32` unless it's making you. 32-bit floating-point only has a 24-bit mantissa anyway, i.e., it only stores exact integers up to 16777216. I'd just scan all integer numbers into `uint64` and be done with it (though you could get away with `uint32` for an 8-digit date).

Comment: @twotwotwo I get this... Scan error on column index 12: converting string "2.0140121e+07" to a uint32: strconv.ParseUint

Comment: Wow--weird. See if scanning into float64 then converting to int preserves the exact value, maybe? (float64 has enough bits in the mantissa at least.) If not, what database driver is this and is the query a plain `select *`/`select colname` or something more complicated (that might make the DB convert to a float internally)?

Comment: As shown in my question, I can scan into float32 and then put it into a uint without issues.  Just looking for a better way.. the db driver is "code.google.com/p/odbc".

Comment: The issue might not be obvious, but `float32`s are inherently imprecise for integers above 16777216, such as the YYYYMMDD value 20141216. So I think you really do want to try a float64 instead. (Going via float64 might have problems too, just saying float32 might initially look like a workable solution but it looks like precision is a problem.)

Comment: Genuinely confused where strings/strconv got involved. https://code.google.com/p/odbc/source/browse/column.go#77 suggests it will default to a C double (==float64); not sure where the strconv happens.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when parsing JSON from a RPC server. I created a function to convert the scientific notation string back to uint like this:

```
func scientificNotationToUInt(scientificNotation string) (uint, error) {
    flt, _, err := big.ParseFloat(scientificNotation, 10, 0, big.ToNearestEven)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    fltVal := fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", flt)
    intVal, err := strconv.ParseInt(fltVal, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return uint(intVal), nil
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/BS1vTuPxx2C)